# How to check if two words are ordered in python

Tags: python

what is the bes way tho check if two words are ordered in sentence and how many times it occurs in python.
For example: I like to eat maki sushi and the best sushi is in Japan. 
words are: [maki, sushi]

Thanks.

The code

```
import re

x="I like to eat maki sushi and the best sushi is in Japan"
x1 = re.split('\W+',x)
l1 = [i for i,m in enumerate(x1) if m == "maki"]
l2 = [i for i,m in enumerate(x1) if m == "sushi"]


ordered = []
for i in l1:
    for j in l2: 
        if j == i+1:
            ordered.append((i,j))

print ordered
```

Comment: any code attempt you could provide yourself?

Comment: added, but not efficient

Comment: So you want "every pair of indices (x, y) such that x < y and the x'th word is 'maki' and the y'th word is 'sushi'"? Or do you want the words to be consecutive? Or just what?

Comment: As you can see in my example they have to be consecutive - y= x+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the added code, you mean that words are adjacent?

Why not just put them together:

```
print len(re.findall(r'\bmaki sushi\b', sent))
```

Comment: No the OP means in order so this answer is useless.

Comment: @jakob - thx this actually solved my problem :) (I also allowed "-" between two words)

Answer (score 1):

```
def ordered(string, words):
    pos = [string.index(word) for word in words]
    return pos == sorted(pos)

s = "I like to eat maki sushi and the best sushi is in Japan"
w =  ["maki", "sushi"]
ordered(s, w) #Returns True.
```

Not exactly the most efficient way of doing it but simpler to understand.

Comment: just to prove it works fine as the example given SHOULD return True. The assert is just to show it doesn't fail

Comment: OK. I liked that you made function for it by the way. But see our discussion about [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234518/how-to-check-if-two-words-are-ordered-in-python/7234654#7234654): I think you do need to split the sentence...

Comment: That is a pretty inappropriate use of `assert`.  Just use a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'I like to eat maki sushi and the best sushi is in Japan'
```

**check order**

```
indices = [s.split().index(w) for w in ['maki', 'sushi']]
sorted(indices) == indices
```

**how to count**

```
s.split().count('maki')
```

---

Note (based on discussion below):

suppose the sentence is *'I like makim more than sushi or maki'*. Realizing that *makim* is another word than *maki*, the word *maki* is placed after *sushi* and occurs only once in the sentence. To detect this and count correctly, the sentence **must be split** over the spaces into the actual words.

Comment: Your doing s.split().index(w). You don't need to.

Comment: yes you do need to split: suppose the sentence was 'I like makimore and maki'. the word 'maki' appears only once. Not using split() would count it twice

Comment: `.index` takes ONLY the first instance

Comment: True. So think about 'I like makimore more than sushi or maki'. Is 'maki' placed before or after 'sushi'? By the way, .count() should be preceeded with split as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if res > 0:
    words are sorted in the sentence

```
words = ["sushi", "maki", "xxx"]
sorted_words = sorted(words)
sen = " I like to eat maki sushi and the best sushi is in Japan xxx";
ind = map(lambda x : sen.index(x), sorted_words)
res = reduce(lambda a, b: b-a, ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution :)

```
import re
sent = 'I like to eat maki sushi and the best sushi is in Japan'
words = sorted(['maki', 'sushi'])
assert re.search(r'\b%s\b' % r'\b.*\b'.join(words), sent)
```

Comment: %s formatting is less future proof considering the newer string.format() method

Answer (score 0):

Just and idea, it might need some more work

```
(sentence.index('maki') <= sentence.index('sushi')) == ('maki' <= 'sushi')
```

Comment: `index()` would give you the lowest index. It would also raise `ValueError` if the word is not in the string. This would work only for the simplest cases.